# How to publish code of multiple repositories to <username>.github.io (Github Pages)

Tags: git, github, repository, github-pages

I have two repositories *Repo A* and *Repo B* and I want to host the code in both the repositories to my github pages repository.

One of the options:

> Move the code inside *Repo A* to a directory *Dir_Repo_A* under *blunderboy.github.io* and I can see my page hosted at blunderboy.github.io/Dir_Repo_A/index.html

And Do the same thing for *Repo B* as well.

But I have a few problems with the approach:

1. All the PRs I get from community, I need to move the code again to Dir_Repo_A.

So Every changes in my original repo, takes a bit of manual effort to reflect in github page.

I want to have something like this. There should be a branch (say gh-pages) in my original repo (Repo A) and then I can merge the master branch into that branch whenever there is a change and just push the code in gh-pages branch to  blunderboy.github.io repo which should reflect the changes on github page.

I think [angular/angular-phonecat](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/) repo is already doing this. I am not sure which steps to follow.

Comment: Look [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)